# logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,6457] and labels shape [16000]

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Estou tentando montar um rede neural com keras

```py
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_teste.shape)
print(y_teste.shape)
```

```
(30000, 500)
(30000, 500)
(70000, 500)
(70000, 500)
```

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding ,LSTM, Dropout, Dense
    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vectorize_layer.vocabulary_size() + 1, 500, input_length=500, name="Embedding"))
model.add(LSTM(500, name=**texto em negrito**'lstm'))
model.add(Dense(vectorize_layer.vocabulary_size(), activation='softmax', name="Dense"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

```py
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1 )
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 2
      1 with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
----> 2     model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1 )
      3 # model.fit(tf.reshape(x_train, ((1) + x_train.shape)), tf.reshape(y_train, ((1) + y_train.shape )), epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:60, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53   # Convert any objects of type core_types.Tensor to Tensor.
     54   inputs = [
     55       tensor_conversion_registry.convert(t)
     56       if isinstance(t, core_types.Tensor)
     57       else t
     58       for t in inputs
     59   ]
---> 60   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     61                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     62 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     63   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits defined at (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 736, in start

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever

  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once

  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 516, in dispatch_queue

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 505, in process_one

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 412, in dispatch_shell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 740, in execute_request

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 546, in run_cell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3024, in run_cell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3079, in _run_cell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3284, in run_cell_async

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3466, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_77474/1686908238.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2493, in run_cell_magic

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 1332, in time

  File "<timed eval>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2493, in run_cell_magic

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyterlab_notify/magics.py", line 91, in notify

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 546, in run_cell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3024, in run_cell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3079, in _run_cell

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3284, in run_cell_async

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3466, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_77474/1618818029.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1783, in fit

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1377, in train_function

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1360, in step_function

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1349, in run_step

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1127, in train_step

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1185, in compute_loss

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 143, in __call__

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 270, in call

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 2454, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy

  File "/home/wemy/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5777, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy

logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,6457] and labels shape [16000]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_12920]
```

estou recebendo o erro acima e não sei por onde seguir para corrigir

queria entender como faço de uma maneira mais facil de entender como conectar as camadas e quais os shapes certo para montar para passar a rede.

Comment: Tente mudar o método de `loss` para `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

conseguir resolver o problema que está bem claro na [documentação](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) e eu tinha passado despercebido.

a camada LSTM aguarda um tensor 3D e eu estava passando um 2D, após ajustar funcionou certinho.